# Why were there Muggles at the Quidditch World Cup?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch, muggles

In Goblet of Fire, there is a Muggle named Roberts who is in charge of giving out campsites. Why did the organizers need him? They could just take any place and enlarge it by magic, without risking Muggles finding out about magic.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, it'd probably be because that much magic would be exhausting and expensive to use.  Whereas having a real camp site chosen and tended to by muggles would be a great deal cheaper and easier.

Comment: So the Death Eaters had somebody to terrorise afterwards.

Comment: It *was* the muggle's field IIRC, so perhaps he made a condition of use for the field being that he managed how it was used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that the [Roberts' campsite](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_World_Cup_Campsite) was simply located in a convenient location near to where the Quiddich World Cup was taking place.

Presumably the sizeable influx of guests from around the world would make it necessary to use all sorts of muggle services for the supply of food and water (neither of which can be magically created) and especially lodgings. It's notable that the Diggory family is assigned to the *next* field over, one owned by a Mr Payne.

> He picked up the dusty kettle and peered inside it. ‘We’ll need water
>   …’ ‘There’s a tap marked on this map the Muggle gave us,’ said Ron,
>   who had followed Harry inside the tent, and seemed completely
>   unimpressed by its extraordinary inner proportions. ‘It’s on the other
>   side of the field.

Out of universe, obviously the Roberts' family serve as a proxy to show how badly the wizarding world (both goodies and baddies) treat muggles. The Ministry are enchanting his memory a dozen times a day and the Death-Eaters are so despicable that they choose to harm his family for the sheer fun of it.

[image: Muggle Campsite]

Comment: This accounts for why the Muggle _structures_ were used; but apart from the out-of-universe bit, I don’t see why the actual _Muggles_ couldn’t just be gotten rid of. It would be so much easier to just enchant them once to believe they’ve won the lottery and have them go on a two-week holiday in Greece (leaving their field to be operated exactly as it is now, but by wizards instead of Muggles), than having to alter their memories dozens of times a day, which (as we know from Bertha Jorkins) is not a risk-free thing to do.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - But then who'd do all the cleaning out of latrines, liaise with the utilities companies, etc? Having the muggles around to act as their slaves must be like having especially smart House Elves.

Comment: Surely wizards could clean out latrines much more efficiently than Muggles—just “vanish the evidence”, as they say. Utilities companies is a better point, but I don’t really think that would be very necessary either, would it? Wizards generally don’t use electricity, the water we see comes from a well (which isn’t likely to get shut down in less than two weeks—and even if it did, _Aguamenti_), Muggle-supplied central heating isn’t likely to be an issue in tents, and food should also be obtainable without Muggle help.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Would you rather *tell someone* to go clean out several dozen latrines or do it yourself, no matter how easy it would be?

Comment: Obviously I’d rather tell someone else to do it. But considering the rather tremendous security risks entailed, having _Muggles_ in particular do it doesn’t seem very prudent. They could even have got rid of the Muggles and just used actual House Elves to do their dirty work as per regular practice. A handful of Muggle-savvy wizards (which we know do exist) working as liaison officers would likely suffice.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess it was just for ease of use - there was no reason to co-ordinate and employ a magical logistic system when a perfectly good muggle one existed.

Possibly it was an ethical issue.  If the field was hired out by the owner and the Wizards wanted to use it then it is only fair that they follow his rules ... although I am not so sure this is a big thing in the wizarding world!